# Better solution than while (reentrantLock.isLocked()) for waiting

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I have a service bean which provides access to a Map. From time to time I need to rebuild the content of the Map wich takes several seconds and I want to block the access to the map while its rebuilding, because it can be accessed from different Threads.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  private Map<Key,Value> cache = null;
  private ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

   public void rebuildCache(){
     try {
       reentrantLock.lock();
       cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
       ... //processing time consuming stuff and building up the cache
       }finally {
        reentrantLock.unlock();
     }
   }
    
   public Value getValue(Key key){
     while (lock.isLocked()){}
     return cache.get(key);
   }
   ...
}
```

As you can see I use

```
while (reentrantLock.isLocked()){}
```

to check if the lock is locked and wait until its unlocked. This solution seems to be quite dirty. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Take look at FutureTask. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html

Comment: Why wouldn't us use lock.lock();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` instead.

In your write method:

```
theLock.writeLock().lock();
try {
    // update the map
} finally {
    theLock.writeLock().unlock();
```

}

In the read method, use the .readLock() instead.

This has the problem however that during the update of the map, all readers will be blocked; another solution would be to use a plain lock to replace the reference of the old map to a new, updated one, and use a plain old `synchronized`.

---

More importantly though, your use of locks is incorrect. You should do:

```
theLock.lock();
try {
    // whatever
} finally {
    theLock.unlock();
}
```

Imagine what happens if the locking fails with your current lock: you'll always try to unlock and you'll end up with an `IllegalLockStateException`.

Comment: ok thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. And thank you for the second advice as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).
With it you can read as many times as you want, as long as read lock is not locked.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  private Map<Key,Value> cache = null;
  private ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

   public void rebuildCache(){
     try {
       reentrantLock.writeLock().lock();
       cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
       ... //processing time consuming stuff and building up the cache
       }finally {
        reentrantLock.writeLock().unlock();
     }
   }

   public Value getValue(Key key){
    if(reentrantLock.getReadLock().lock()){
     return cache.get(key);
    }finally{
       reentrantLock.getReadLock().unlock();
    }
   }
   ...
}
```